# Customized Base64 algorithme

Tags: java, android, base64

We made a custom base64 encode algorithme.
This code work on Android finally

```
byte b = (((bArr[i4] & 255) << 16) |((bArr[i4 + 1] & 255) << 8) | (bArr[i4 + 2] & 255));
```

However, when i tried to write the same line in **java on linux** it says:

```
incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```

I can't cast the whole variable because it made an error in base64 encoding

Could anyone give me the reason why ?

Comment: Aside from the compiler error, what you've written doesn't really make sense. `somethingThatFitsInAByte << 16` just doesn't fit in a byte.

Comment: The same code works fine on Android application